# Dowload PDF in Dolphin Mini?

Tags: pdf, dolphin-browser

It seems to be a relatively new feature that pdf files are shown directly in the browser instead of downloading them.

How can I download them instead?

Comment: I have updated to the latest Dolphin, but it asks me to download the PDF file. Have you tried with a different site? Just to test, search for a PDF file in Google, and try to download it. Let me know if it still opens on the screen for you.

Comment: @geffchang Upps. You are right! There seems to be a difference between Dolphin and Mini in that aspect - I updated the title of my question accordingly. I tried with mini and assumed this to be a general behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dolphin Mini blog post](http://dolphin.com/find-pdf-viewer-in-dolphin-browser-mini-v1-2-beta/) documents how to download the PDF file.

> **Q2: How to download PDF files?**
>
> A2: 1) long press the link of PDF files, choose the “save link” option
>   in context menu. 2) click “download” option at the bottom of the page
>   after you click the link.

Comment: Can you answer the [follow-up-question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/65408/31824) as well?